# Delete alert php

Tags: php

So I want to make a website
where when you delete a post
it will show an alert msg that the post has been deleted successfully
but the problem is that when I am reloading
the alert is still there

Can't figure any fix for the issue
if I try to use `header('location: ./wb_submission.php');`
the echo will not load

code I am trying ->

```php
    if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
        $sno = $_GET['delete'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM `website_submit` WHERE `sno` = $sno";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        The submission was deleted successfully!
      </div>';
    }
```

Comment: Do you redirect user agent to `./wb_submission.php` which contains the code that deletes the record?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: Never use `$_GET` to delete stuff. Any crawler will delete all your data.

Comment: what can I do then?

Comment: Only ppl who are authorized can access the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `delete` parameter from URL after page loaded. You can do it with js:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '', location.href.replace(location.search, ""));
```

### How it works

1. this method modifies the current URL without putting this into history

```
window.history.replaceState
```

2. First parameter: `{}`

> The state object is a JavaScript object which is associated with the history entry passed to the replaceState method. The state object can be null.

3. Second parameter: `''`

> This parameter exists for historical reasons, and cannot be omitted; passing the empty string is traditional, and safe against future changes to the method.

4. Third parameter (new URL):
   first part (`location.href`) is complete URL value, like:

   `http://example.com/page.php?delete=10`

   then it will replace search parameters with empty string:

```
.replace(location.search, "")
```

`location.search` is everything after ? in URL (in this case: `?delete=10`)

[History.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState)

### Edit

If you have multiple parameters in your URL and you want to remove only delete parameter try this code:

```
// Create new URLSearchParams object
// location.search is something like "?delete=10&msg=hello&ok=true"
let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

// Remove delete parameter from URL parameters
params.delete("delete");

// Convert parameters to string
// e.g "msg=hello&ok=true"
let urlParams = params.toString();

// if urlParams is not empty add a question mark before it:
urlParams = urlParams.length > 0 ? "?" + urlParams : "";

// Replace new parameters
window.history.replaceState({}, '', urlParams);
```